# MVC getting data from textbox and store in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am really new to mvc and I am still trying it out. Could you kindly guide me how to get data from textbox and store this in a database. At the moment I am using the below code.

View:

```
<h3 style="color:#ffe718";>Enter Email: </h3><input type="text">
    <input style="margin-top:10px;" type="button" class="loginButton" title="Register" value="Register" />
```

A textbox and a register button for the user to enter email and register

Model:

```
public class MailModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Subscribe(MailModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Mail mm = new Mail();
            mm.mail1 = model.Email;
            new Data.MailAccess().addMail(mm);
        }

        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

How can I connect the model with the view and the view with the controller please.

Comment: Start with an [mvc tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc+tutorial), there are too many out there to count.

Comment: Yes there are many things that you have to consider.

Comment: A good tutorial is at http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/asp.net-mvc-tutorials

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the view tell the view what model class to use:

```
@model MailModel
```

You may have to use the full type name including the namespaces like this

```
@model FullNameSpace.MailModel
```

Where `FullNameSpace` is the actual namespace.

The input has to use the property name as it's own name and can include the value if you need to reshow the view:

```
<input type="text" name="Email" value="@Model.Email">
```

A shorter form to write that is

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
```

Specify the name of the controller action as the action of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="Subscribe">
```

Comment: thank toy very much :) any how about the action on button click?

Comment: do I need to use<% ? as I am geting the @Html.Textbox as text in web

Comment: @CarlaFenech just start with the @. Forget everything you know about asp.net. asp.net MVC has nothing in common with classic asp.net form.